# Why is my selector not selecting a record in my customized screen? Am I missing something? Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Here is My DAC Field for the Selector.
It seems fine on the first run, but when I select through the selector, its just blinks, or nothing happens, but when I nagivate through the next and previous buttons it selects the records.

```
#region RQBatchNbr
[PXDBString(15, IsKey =true, InputMask ="")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Batch Nbr", Required = true)]
[PXSelector(
        typeof(Search<GNRequest.rQBatchNbr>),
        typeof(GNRequest.prefixCode),
        typeof(GNRequest.description),
        DescriptionField = typeof(GNRequest.description) 
)]
[AutoNumber(
        typeof(Search<GNSetup.requestBatchNumberingID>),
        typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate)
)]
#endregion
```

Comment: Check if control in ASPX is a PXSelector and double check key fields to make sure they are properly initialized on insert.

Comment: Also make sure on your graph extension, you have a Dataview for GNSetup. Ex: 
public PXSetup<GNSetup> GNSetup; public YourGraphMaint(){ GNSetup gnSetup = GNSetup .Current;  .... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little weird, but I just Redo the whole ASPX Page. it turns out to be working as it is.

Comment: Oddly enough, this was my experience as well, only on an existing screen. I deleted the grid it was part of, re-added it, and it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

One reason can be that you have forgotten setting `IsUnicode = true` in the `PXDBStringAttribute`.
Another one can be related to the `typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate)` in the `AutoNumberAttribute`. Try adding `Date` field to your `DAC` and passing him instead of `AccessInfo.businessDate`.

Comment: I've also defined that in my DAC. :(